# Time complexity of loop over an array plus arr.indexOf() another array

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o

I have the below function and I am not 100% sure of the time complexity of it.  The purpose for the function is to return a uniquified version of `arr`.  The function iterates over `arr` and checks if it exists in the `uniqueObjects` array (`arr` is an array of objects, and we don't want to remove copies, we just want to remove duplicate references to the same object in memory).

```
function uniquifyArray(arr) {
    var uniqueObjects = [];
    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(uniqueObjects.indexOf(arr[i])==-1) {
            uniqueObjects.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return uniqueObjects;
}
```

The best that I can reason is that the time complexity is `O(n+m)` where `n` is the size of `arr` and `m` is the size of `uniqueObjects`.  I know that `uniqueObjects.indexOf()` is `O(n)` but the thing I'm unsure of is that we aren't 100% sure of the size of `uniqueObjects` until we completely iterate over all of `arr`.  `uniqueObjects` is an array that may grow with each iteration.

Assume that you are calling the function as so:

```
var objects = [
    {id:1}, //unique in memory
    {id:2}, //unique in memory
    {id:3}, //unique in memory
    {id:1}  //reference in memory to object at objects[0]
    {id:2}  //reference in memory to object at objects[1]
];
var uniqueObjects = uniquifyArray(objects);
/*
 * uniqueObjects = [
 *    {id:1},
 *    {id:2},
 *    {id:3}
 * ]
 */
```

While I don't mind seeing more efficient solutions, I would like to figure out the complexity for the function I have written above.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have some data to illustrate the problem?

Comment: I added some clarification.  It's hard to represent, but essentially the function removes objects that are references to other objects.  The function works as intended, but just having difficulty computing the time complexity

Comment: I would think that the complexity would be more of O(n*m) plus some constant for additional statements (which would be negligible towards infinity). See this for the algorithm of the indexOf statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: for a better performance, i would use a hash table with a unique identifier, like `id`, if you can rely on that. this would result to O(n+m).

Comment: @NinaScholz A hash table would work for removing copies of objects but not for removing duplicates of objects in memory

Comment: @NinaScholz Why would it be O(n+m) and not O(N) with a hash lookup that takes O(1)?

Comment: @plalx, you are right, O(n+m) is anyway linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be `O(N2)`. An easy way to make it `O(N)` would be to use a `Map` rather than an `Array` to track unique objects, making the lookup `O(1)`.

```js
var o1 = { id: 1 }, 
    o2 = { id: 2 },
    objects = [o1, o1, o2, o2, o2];

alert(uniquifyArray(objects).length);

function uniquifyArray(arr) {
  
  var objMap = new Map();
  
  return arr.filter(function (obj) {
    if (!objMap.has(obj)) {
      objMap.set(obj, true);
      return true;
    }
    
    return false;
  });  
}
```

Comment: This function worked for me.  Can you breakdown how this becomes O(n)

Comment: Also for testing purposes, try adding and o3 = o2 when declaring your objects at the top.  We want to remove duplicates in memory, not ones with duplicate properties

Comment: @MichaelHamilton The repetition of the same object in the array does the same thing. There wouldn't be any computational difference if I added o3 = o2 and did [o1, o2, o3] since that would be equivalent to [o1, o2, o2] and that's what I already do ;)

Comment: Really, in time complexity analysis, constants are dropped, so regardless of whether the procedure takes 1N or 2N or 100N, it is still an O(n) algorithm because the number of steps scale linearly in proportion to the size of the data.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the objects itself, with a temporary property, which is in the final loop deleted. Complexity **O(n+m)**.

```js
function uniquifyArray(arr) {
    var uniqueObjects = arr.filter(function (a) {
        if (!a.___) {
            a.___ = true;
            return true;
        }
    });
    uniqueObjects.forEach(function (a) {
        delete a.___;
    });
    return uniqueObjects;
}

var id1 = { id: 1 }, id2 = { id: 2 }, id3 = { id: 3 },
    objects = [id1, id2, id3, id1, id2, id3, id1],
    uniqueObjects = uniquifyArray(objects);

console.log(uniqueObjects);
```

Answer (score 1):

The complexity would be `O(n^2)`, where `n` is the length of `arr`.

The for loop is time `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of `arr`. In each iteration of the loop, `uniqueObjects.indexOf(...)` is called, which is time complexity `O(m)`, where `m` is the length of uniqueObjects.

Therefore, the overall time complexity is `O(nm)`. However, this can be simplified to `O(n^2)`, since `m` has an upper bound of `n`.

Comment: Would O(n^2) be an asymptotically tight bound? What if `n` is significantly greater than `m`? This would seem to be more like o(n^2) instead.

Comment: FWIW, let's say `n` is 100 objects, 50 of which are duplicates, `m` will eventually become 50 objects long, but it won't become that long until all of `n` has been iterated over.
If `n` is 100 objects long but only 1 of which is a duplicate, the longest `m` will ever be is 1

Comment: This is why it is O(n^2) rather than ϴ(n^2). Big-O is just an upper bound, where ϴ is a tight bound. Here is some more information: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19141/what-is-an-asymptotically-tight-upper-bound @MichaelHamilton